# Copy file (w/o using FileUtils)

Tags: ruby, file, io, copy, marshalling

So I thought that Marshal was the best way to solve it. I load the file and immediately dump it. But I get this error:
"incompatible marshal file format (can't be read) format version 4.8 required; 91.112 given"

```
  def self.copy_file(src, dest)
    File.open(src) do |src_file|
      File.open(dest, 'w') do |dest_file|
        Marshal.dump(Marshal.load(src_file), dest_file)
      end
    end
  end
```

I can't use the FileUtils because I use a certain 'Ruby variant' that doesn't have that library. And I'm not aware of any free FileUtils.dll that is standalone and redistributable. And even if it were, I still prefer my script to go without any extra .dll files.
And without FileUtils File.copy() doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: Are you just trying to copy a file?

Comment: Yes just a simple file copy.

Comment: Do you want to copy both text and binary files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
def self.copy_file(src, dest)
  File.write(dest, File.read(src))
end
```

Or for more ancient versions of ruby that don't have `File.write`:

```
def self.copy_file(src, dest)
  File.open(dest, 'w') { |f| f.write(File.read(src)) }
end
```

Comment: Which ruby version are you using?

Comment: A stripped down version/build of Ruby 1.9.2 called RGSS. But that edit you just made solved it :). Thanks

Comment: No problem. There's always a way in ruby ;)

Comment: `read` and `write` are defined in the class `IO` ([IO#read](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/IO.html#method-c-read) and [IO#write](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/IO.html#method-c-write)) and `File.ancestors.first(2)
=> [File, IO]`.